# Subdivide mesh WITHOUT creating new faces?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, topology

Is there a way to subdivide a mesh without creating new faces? To clarify, I want to somehow "subdivide" all edges of a mesh, but keep the face count the same as before.

Example: A quad would turn into an octagon while still maintaining the shape of the original quad.

Comment: You can in edit mode, select an edge and subdivide it, the edge will subdivide and add the respective new vertices in without changing the shape of the object. I don't know why you'd want to do this because 3D renderers always triangulate the mesh before rendering (you just don't see it), by creating n-gons (multiple edged polygons) the renderer will have to guess on face orientation with a multi sided polygon so you might end up with rendering artifacts. Creating n-gons with a deforming mesh is a bad idea due to the above.

Comment: i want to apply a wireframe modifier afterwards, that's why the ngons are important. i need the additional vertices to displace them randomly BEFORE applying the wireframe modifier, creating a shape key and blending between the shape key and the original shape depending on the amplitude of an audio signal.

Comment: You can: delete only faces, subdivide, refill with F, on a well-formed mesh. Does that constitute an answer?

Comment: Yes, that actually did the trick! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it for others who might need this in the future?

Comment: @MQwadezo Perhaps - if you do not need the faces and just keep them for the _Wireframe_ modifier - you could also try using a _Skin_ modifier. It does not need faces to create a mesh along the edges.